# Having a problem understanding overloaded super call

Tags: java

Why does variable `size` equal to 5 instead of 10? Doesn't the `super(lglist)` call increment the value of size by 5?

```
class V2Radiator {
    int size=0;

    V2Radiator(ArrayList list) {
        for (int x = 0; x<5; x++) {
            list.add(new SimUnit("V2Radiator"));
            size++;
        }

    }
}

class V3Radiator extends V2Radiator {
    V3Radiator(ArrayList lglist) {
        super(lglist);
        for(int g=0; g<10; g++) {
            lglist.add(new SimUnit("V3Radiator"));
        }
    }   
}

public class TestLifeSupportSim {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList aList = new ArrayList();
        V2Radiator v2 = new V2Radiator(aList);
        V3Radiator v3 = new V3Radiator(aList);
        System.out.println(v2.size);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well yes, but that's all it does.  It's just +5 period, you never increase `size` in the child class constructor.

Comment: "Doesn't the super(lglist) call increment the value of size by 5?" it does, but it only increases it 5 times. Which part of your code do you think should make it 15?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why should it be 10? In `V2Radiator v2 = new V2Radiator(aList);` the object `v2` has an instance member `size` which is incremented to 5 when it is instantiated inside the for loop.

When you instantiate `V3Radiator v3 = new V3Radiator(aList);` you are creating a new instance `v3` which is totally a new instance of `V3Radiator` and different from the earlier instance `v2`.

So the `v2` instance is not affected by the instantiation of `v3` and `v3` has its own copy of the `size` instance variable inherited from `V2Radiator`. The `v3` instance when initialized is incrementing its own copy of the `size` variable to 5 by calling the super class constructor.

So you need to make the size variable static in that case the same value would be shared across `v2` and `v3`. On instantiating `v3` you would also increment the `size` to 10.

```
class V2Radiator {
 static int size=0;

 V2Radiator(ArrayList list) {
     for (int x = 0; x<5; x++) {
        list.add(new SimUnit("V2Radiator"));
        size++;
     }    
  }
}

class V3Radiator extends V2Radiator {
 V3Radiator(ArrayList lglist) {
    super(lglist); //here size variable will be incremented for all instances.
    for(int g=0; g<10; g++) {
        lglist.add(new SimUnit("V3Radiator"));
    }
  }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You explained it very well. All clear now

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the `size++;` call from `V3Radiator`'s constructor.

In that case the correct sizes are:

v2.size - 5

v3.size - 15

V2Radiator

```
import java.util.List;

class V2Radiator {
    int size = 0;

    V2Radiator(List<SimUnit> list) {
        for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
            list.add(new SimUnit("V2Radiator"));
            size++;
        }

    }
}
```

V3Radiator

```
import java.util.List;

class V3Radiator extends V2Radiator {
    V3Radiator(List<SimUnit> lglist) {
        super(lglist);
        for(int g = 0; g < 10; g++) {
            lglist.add(new SimUnit("V3Radiator"));
            size++;
        }
    }
}
```

Some explanation for the changes I made:

You should use the List<> interface instead of ArrayList<> in your constructor, so the caller can decide the implementation of that interface

You should add the type parameter to that list, so the caller cannot pass for example a List to your constructor